# c pointer to pointer how to iterate through it

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pointer-to-pointer

```
struct hashLink

{
   KeyType key; /*the key is what you use to look up a hashLink*/
   ValueType value; /*the value stored with the hashLink, an int in our case*/
   struct hashLink *next; /*notice how these are like linked list nodes*/
};

struct hashMap
{
    hashLink ** table; /*array of pointers to hashLinks*/
    int tableSize; /*number of buckets in the table*/
    int count; /*number of hashLinks in the table*/
};
```

I'm trying to iterate through a hashMap with hashLinks. Is this the correct approach? The hashLinks are in an array and may have more hashLinks linked to them in a linked list. I just do not understand how to work pointers to pointers. tableSize is the amount of elements in the array. At each array position there may be more hashLinks linked to the first there.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ht->tableSize; i ++)
{
    hashLink *current;

    if (ht->table[i] != 0)
    {
        current = ht->table[i];

        while(current->next !=0)
        {
            hashLink *next;
            next = current->next;
            free(current->key);
            free(current);
            current = next;
        }

        free(current->key);
        free(current);
    }
    else 
    {
        continue;
    }

        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have done it *exactly* like this, but similar. That is to say, it looks okay to me at a quick glance. Oh, and in C you should really use `NULL` for null pointers.

Comment: Are you serious? Because I have no idea what I'm doing...

Comment: To add to my previous comment, it looks okay at a quick glance ***if*** all pointers are allocated correctly or otherwise initialized. :) As for the pointer to pointer issue, just look at it like an array of pointers.

Comment: nitpick: `array of pointers to hashLinks` --> `pointer to pointer to hashLinks`

Comment: `while(current->next !=0)` -->> `while(current != NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this does work, but you end up with a hashtable that contains dangling pointers. Also, as Joachim noted, it works as long as you assume that the values contained in the structs are sane, i.e., `tableSize` contains the number of entries in `table` and the `hashLink`s have been correctly allocated.

Your iteration through the links is fine and correclty `free`s all the `hashLink`s in the table. However, consider the state of `ht` after the iteration. You do not change the values of `ht->table[i]` at all, so after you leave the loop, the pointers will still be stored in the table. If you want to reuse the table, you should set the pointers to 0 when you do not need them anymore, i.e., add `ht->table[i] = 0` somewhere after `current = ht->table[i];`.

If this method is part of the "destructor" of the table (i.e., some method like `hashmap_delete(...)`), then you can simply `free` the hashmap after you finished your iteration, i.e., add `free(ht);` after the `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified:

```
for(int i=0; i < ht->tableSize; i++)
{
    hashLink *current;

    while (ht->table[i] != NULL) {
        current = ht->table[i];
        ht->table[i] = current->next;

        free(current->key);
        free(current);
    }
}
```

It can be further simplified to **only one loop**, but that is left as an exercise to the reader ...

---

Note: as a side effect, this will set all the pointers in ht->table[] to NULL; which is good, since after freeing the linked lists they have become *stale* anyway.